# C# Windows Forms - move element when resizing the form

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog, responsive

I need some help with a responsive form in WinForms. I have a Checkbox at Position xy. When i resize the form to a smaller size, this Checkbox should move to the left side, closer to the other elements.

You can see it on the pictures I made. I do not know, which Property I have to change there, to make this happen. The checkbox to move is marked by the red box.

When I enlarge the form, this element has to stay at its default position. When I reduce it, the checkbox has to move to the left. When I enlarge it again, the Checkbox has to move back to its default position.

[image: this is the default form]

[image: the form is smaller now, the checkbox has to move to the left]

Comment: Look at Anchor property

Comment: Steve beat me to it, (almost) every control has an Anchor property.

Comment: I updated my explanation :) The added information: When I enlarge the form, this element has to stay at its default position. When I reduce it, the checkbox has to move to the left. When I enlarge it again, the Checkbox has to move back to its default position.

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the [`Anchor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.anchor) property:

```
checkBox1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right;
```

This states that the right border of the control should always have the same distance to the right border of the containing control (your form).

You can also set this property in the designer window.

---

Update after your clarification:

This is a complicated situation. One solution I found (though I'm not sure it's the best) could be to use a `Panel` to contain the `CheckBox`.

- Place the `Panel` at the left-most position the `CheckBox` could have
- Set the size of the `Panel` so that the right border is at the right-most border (plus a few pixels) the `CheckBox` should have
- Set the `MaximumSize` of the `Panel` to this exact size
- Set the `Anchor` property of the `Panel` to `Top | Left | Right`
- Place the `CheckBox` inside the `Panel` at the right edge
- Set the `Anchor` property of the `CheckBox` to `Top | Right`

Now, if you enlarge the `Form`, the `Panel` keeps its size because of the `MaximumSize` value.

If you shrink the `Form`, the `Panel` will also shrink because of its `AnchorStyle.Right`. The `CheckBox` moves to the left because of its own `AnchorStyle.Right`.

When you enlarge the `Form` again, the `Panel` also grows, but only it reaches its `MaximumSize` again. The `CheckBox` moves to the right to keep up with the growing `Panel`.

Hope this does what you want. I can later add screenshots if necessary.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I did not explain it well enough. It already got the Anchor Top and Left. Because when I make the form bigger, the Checkbox has to stay at its position. It just has to move to the left, when it gets smaller. This is my problem

Comment: @peterHasemann so your question seems underspecified. This is a complicated requirement. Should it always stay at its position if you enlarge the form? even if it was moved to the left before because of shrinking the form? What may help you is to define a minimum size of the form. Shrink it to that minimum size in designer, set the position of the checkbox and set only the right anchor. Then resize the form to its _default_ form. Now the behaviour should come close to what you want. If not, it seems you will have to implement the behaviour by yourself, using the `SizeChanged` event of the Form

Comment: When I enlarge the form, this element has to stay at its default position. When I reduce it, the checkbox has to move to the left. When I enlarge it again, the Checkbox has to move back to its default position. Hope this was a better explanation.

Comment: I tried to use the SizeChanged-Event. So when this is called, I calculate the horizontalPosition of this element. But I will also test your suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

So i tried to get a clean code solution for this, i hope this will work for everyone:

```
private void CtrlSequence_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) // Form got reduced / enlarged    
{
      checkBox.Location = new Point(Math.Min(Width - checkBox.Width, 345), checkBox.Location.Y);    // Width = Forms Width
}
```

Important! This is just meant for the horizontal movement. The vertical is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use TableLyoutPanel.
With this element you can set Column and Row size in type Percent, and set value "left,right,top,bottom to the properties Anchor for TableLyoutPanel and for all element insaid it.

[image]

[image]